# I want to do running total of BRASS (cumulative) of each MM month wise in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

[image: Image example to understand. enter image description here]

I want to do running total of BRASS (cumulative) of each MM month wise in google sheet. every month MM should start running total from beginning but should not add previous month. I have a formula that I pasted in G3. and I m getting running total but adding previous month.

Comment: Pls share a spreadsheet. People are most likely to not help when there is a lot of data involved but only a screenshot is attached. It is like asking them to create a sheet which they need to fill in by themselves (copy the data of your screenshot) then find the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Thank You Mr. Mike Steelson for your reply. Here is the link of the spreadsheet 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18oORKDOvGW15rREQpWl6XuodI4EmANKfsddjlzTwiM8/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Formula which I used. 

=ArrayFormula(
     if(
        len(C3:C),
        MMULT(
           N(ROW(C3:C)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(C3:C)))*N(C3:C=TRANSPOSE(C3:C)),
           N(D3:D)
        ),
     )
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=arrayformula(mmult((transpose(MONTH(B3:B))=MONTH(B3:B))*(transpose(row(D3:D))<=row(D3:D)),1*D3:D))
```

Comment: Thank You Mr. Mike Steelson. You made my day. I have altered your Formula with Wat i Had Used. I achieved .Thanks A TON :) 
=ArrayFormula(
     if(
        len(C3:C),
        MMULT((transpose(MONTH(B3:B))=MONTH(B3:B))*
           N(ROW(C3:C)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(C3:C)))*N(C3:C=TRANSPOSE(C3:C)),
           N(D3:D)
        ),
     )
)

Comment: =ArrayFormula( if( len(C3:C), MMULT((transpose(MONTH(B3:B))=MONTH(B3:B))* N(ROW(C3:C)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(C3:C)))*N(C3:C=TRANSPOSE(C3:C)), N(D3:D) ), ) )